# Uninstalling particular plugin from Jenkins

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle, build, jenkins-groovy

I have AWS instance hosted which has jenkins setup with version 2.11. Currently jenkins has latest version as 2.206 . I am developing an Android Application which has CI/CD integration with this jenkins version.

Recently I migrated from Google Analytics to Firebase Analytics as a result I needed to upgrade my Gradle system to 3.4.2.

I was trying to intall gradle plugin on Jenkins but it showed me a warning "This is build for jenkins verison 2.160 or newer. It may or may not work on your jenkins".

I installed the plugin and there was error with Groovy dependancty.

After that I refreshed the jenkins and Boom Jenkins Crashed

```
hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad: org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorException: java.lang.Error: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:244)
Caused by: org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorException: java.lang.Error: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.execute(Reactor.java:269)
    at jenkins.InitReactorRunner.run(InitReactorRunner.java:45)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.executeReactor(Jenkins.java:1010)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.<init>(Jenkins.java:878)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:85)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:81)
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:227)
Caused by: java.lang.Error: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder.invoke(TaskMethodFinder.java:110)
    at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder$TaskImpl.run(TaskMethodFinder.java:175)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:282)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$7.runTask(Jenkins.java:999)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:210)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder.invoke(TaskMethodFinder.java:104)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: jenkins.model.Jenkins.get()Ljenkins/model/Jenkins;
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.nodes.StepDescriptorCache.getPublicCache(StepDescriptorCache.java:48)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.nodes.StepDescriptorCache.invalidateGlobalCache(StepDescriptorCache.java:55)
    ... 13 more
```

I have searched about this and only solution I found is to uninstall all the plugins and then restart jenkins and again install plugins.

Is there any better way to just delete a particular plugin as I don't know what can be consequences of these on my existing jobs.

Thanks in Advance